# Push notification error in android?

Tags: android, push-notification

I have created a android application. in this application I have used the push notification concept.the notification send properly and also received properly at the receiver end. but the problem is that the same two notification display two times at the receiver end. please tell me what is the problem.

here is my code:

```
 @Override
 protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent)
 {
  Log.e(TAG, "Received message");

 // String res=intent.getStringExtra("state");
  //Log.e("res",res);
  Log.e("full1 ",""+intent.getExtras().toString());
 // Log.e("full2 ",""+intent.getData().toString());
  //Log.e("full3 ",""+intent.toString());

  String message="";

  String id ="";

  String name ="";

  String state ="";

  String desti ="";

  String mobile_no ="";

  String pickup_time="";

  String unit="";

  String street="";

  String suburb="";

  String city="";

  String fare="";

  String group="";

  String date_of_creation="";

  String sender_name="";

  String sender_email="";

  String sender_mobile="";

  String sender_rating="";

  try
  {
  // message = intent.getStringExtra("data");

   //JSONObject  jsonObject = new JSONObject(message);

  // JSONArray array = new JSONArray(intent.getStringExtra("data"));



   /*for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++)
   {*/
    //JSONObject jsonObject2 = array.getJSONObject(o);

    id = intent.getStringExtra("id");

    message = intent.getStringExtra("message");

    name = intent.getStringExtra("name");

    mobile_no = intent.getStringExtra("mobile_no");

    unit = intent.getStringExtra("unit");

    street = intent.getStringExtra("street_name");

    suburb = intent.getStringExtra("suburb");

    state = intent.getStringExtra("state");

    date_of_creation = intent.getStringExtra("date_of_creation");

    desti = intent.getStringExtra("destionation");

    group = intent.getStringExtra("group");

    pickup_time = intent.getStringExtra("pickup_time");

    fare = intent.getStringExtra("fare");

    city =intent.getStringExtra("city");

    sender_name = intent.getStringExtra("sender_name");

    sender_mobile = intent.getStringExtra("sender_mobile");

    sender_email = intent.getStringExtra("sender_email");

    sender_rating = intent.getStringExtra("sender_rating");


  // }
  }
  catch(Exception e)
  {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 displayMessage(context, message);


  generateNotification(context, name, id, state, desti, mobile_no,pickup_time,unit,street,suburb,city,fare,group,sender_name,sender_mobile,sender_email,sender_rating);

 }

 @Override
 protected void onDeletedMessages(Context context, int total) 
 {
  Log.i(TAG, "Received deleted messages notification");
  String message = "Gcm deleted "+total;
  displayMessage(context, message);
  // notifies user
  //generateNotification(context, message);
 }

 @Override
 public void onError(Context context, String errorId) 
 {
  Log.i(TAG, "Received error: " + errorId);
  displayMessage(context, " Error "+ errorId);
 }

 @Override
 protected boolean onRecoverableError(Context context, String errorId) 
 {
  // log message
  Log.i(TAG, "Received recoverable error: " + errorId);
  displayMessage(context, "Gcm recovereable error" +errorId);
  return super.onRecoverableError(context, errorId);
 }

 /**
  * Issues a notification to inform the user that server has sent a message.
  */
 /*private static void generateNotification(Context context, String message)
 {
  int icon = R.drawable.windows;

  long when = System.currentTimeMillis();

  NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =new NotificationCompat.Builder(context).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.windows).setContentTitle(message).setContentText(message);

  // Creates an explicit intent for an Activity in your app

  SharedPreferences spf = context.getSharedPreferences("MYID", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

  String noti_ring = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION).toString();

  if(spf.getString("noti_ring", "").equals(""))
  {
   spf.edit().putString("noti_ring", noti_ring).commit();
  }
  else
  {
   noti_ring = spf.getString("noti_ring", "");
  }

  mBuilder.setSound(Uri.parse(noti_ring));

  mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);

  Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, ViewRecievedJobs.class);

  resultIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

  // The stack builder object will contain an artificial back stack for the
  // started Activity.
  // This ensures that navigating backward from the Activity leads out of
  // your application to the Home screen.
  TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);

  // Adds the back stack for the Intent (but not the Intent itself)
  stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);

  // Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack
  stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);

  PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

  mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

  NotificationManager mNotificationManager =(NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

  mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());

 }*/
 private static void generateNotification(Context context,String name, String id,String state,String desc,String mobileno, String picktime, String unit, String street, String suburb, String city, String fare, String group,String sender_name,String sender_mobile,String sender_email,String sender_rating) 
 {
  int icon = R.drawable.windows;

  long when = System.currentTimeMillis();

  NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =new NotificationCompat.Builder(context).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.windows).setContentTitle(name).setContentText(name);

  // Creates an explicit intent for an Activity in your app

  SharedPreferences spf = context.getSharedPreferences("MYID", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

  String noti_ring = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION).toString();

  if(spf.getString("noti_ring", "").equals(""))
  {
   spf.edit().putString("noti_ring", noti_ring).commit();
  }
  else
  {
   noti_ring = spf.getString("noti_ring", "");
  }

  mBuilder.setSound(Uri.parse(noti_ring));

  mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);

  Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, ViewRecievedJobs.class);

  resultIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

  TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);

  // Adds the back stack for the Intent (but not the Intent itself)
  stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);

  // Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack
  stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);

  PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

  mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

  NotificationManager mNotificationManager =(NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

  mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());

  System.out.println("Context "+context);

  DatabaseAdmin admin = new DatabaseAdmin(context);

  admin.insert_user(id, name, mobileno, picktime,unit,street,suburb, city, state,desc,fare,group,"1",sender_name,sender_mobile,sender_email,sender_rating);

 // MyService.msg_id_list.add(id);


 }

}
```

Comment: please post your code too so it will be good to see your issue

Comment: i HAVE ATTACHED THE CODE PLEASE CHECK THIS....

Answer (score 0):

At receiver side i mean the code in which you are receiving the push notification 
onMessage() method of GCMIntent service there will be logic of
generationOfPushNotification

```
  NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);

        String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        // set intent so it does not start a new activity
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent intent =
                PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        // Play default notification sound
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

        // Vibrate if vibrate is enabled
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
        notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
```

this code is use to generate push notification in which the last line is

```
**notificationManager.notify(0, notification);**
```

means **Post a notification to be shown in the status bar.**

where **0** is the id

and

**notification** is the object of notification manger

when you generate notification every time it execute generation code for notification
where id of notification will always be

**0**

thats why it shows same notification twice or more time

so you need to pass **static variable** in it instead of **0**

so line will be

```
  notificationManager.notify(id, notification); 
  id++;
```

where **id** is a static variable so when next time you get notification its id will be different

hope it will solve your problem it worked for me..

Comment: brother see my answer 
 mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build()); you used 1 as a id in this line please read my answer and do specific changes in it it will solve your problem

Comment: you need to pass static variable in
 mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build()); this line instead of 1 so everytime when new notification generate it will generate with new id instead of same id 1

Comment: hello bro....protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) this method is called twice on single push...